# Split Array property from an Array of Objects into two separate Arrays

Tags: typescript

I want so extract two values from an array holding both of the mentioned values in a single property of an object.
Included you can find my code as well as a Stackblitz project. 
I don´t know what to do inside the `.map()` call in order to split the coords property into two x and y arrays.

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ckpxyz?file=index.ts

```
class MyClass {
  coords: number[];

  constructor(coords: number[]) {
    this.coords = coords;
  }
}

var myList: MyClass[] = [
  new MyClass([1,2]),
  new MyClass([3,4]),
  new MyClass([5,6]),
  new MyClass([7,8]),
  new MyClass([9,10]),
]

myList.map((myObj: MyClass) => {
  console.log(myObj.coords[0], myObj.coords[1]);
  // what to do here to split the array?
});

// GOAL:
// x:number[] = [1,3,5,7,9];
// y:number[] = [2,4,6,8,10];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ES6 array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Array_destructuring) to do that for you. Instead of using `Array.prototype.map`, you should use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) because you can iterate through the entire `myList` once, and then store the `x` and `y` coordinates in separate sub-arrays:

```
const [x, y] = myList.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
  // Unpack/destructure nested arrays
  const [x, y] = accumulator;

  // Push coordinates into sub-arrays
  x.push(currentValue.coords[0]);
  y.push(currentValue.coords[1]);

  // Repack and return updated accumulated values
  return [x, y];
}, [[], []] as [number[], number[]]);
```

In the code above, you basically initialise the reduction process with an array that has the shape of a tuple containing array of numbers, i.e. `[number[], number[]]`, where the first array stores your x coordinates and the second stores your y coordinates.

In each iteration of the reduce, you unpack/destructure the subarrays using `const [x, y] = <currentValueReference>`. Then, you simply push `coords[0]` (which is your x coordinate) and `coords[1]` (which is your y coordinate) into the unpacked arrays.

Then, you repack the arrays by simple returning `[x, y]`.

[See proof-of-concept example here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=22&ssc=38&pln=17&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBhcVoG8BQ1rAPa4CcATCALmgDsBXAWwCMBTAgbQF0BuDLHXCiAFwJVg-QgAo8hEuWr0mbAJTpu2fgAsAlhAB0k4jAC8PKRE7YAvhksYAbmALQa8ADJb+5BMkgQ20I824KBgB3OCQUCDFmAEYAGgAmVgVYwJCwrygogGZYgBYklOwg0M8IqIBWWIA2AtSS8O8ogHZYgA5aorTSxuYATljogAZa1i48Pn5oZgAPWOh4Vj9HFzdtAgYiYQYxMTBgYFoqcFECOYOCdYp+ADUwECoGJQMAPmVscYEp2fnFoz2DmhHMAnMzQabaAAOVAgagkVAuDCut3uDF0+H0zGGClB8Eh0Nh50uNzuDzRJhiSVB6348IoXzmC045jmzDYLNYi0gU1kjBYrDmPPkHOxXAA9KLoABxADyAEFnKQMOKwaRBXyljFYjlKi1ehwlRL4KraLzfP54nlqm0BsNOB9cCBUSBcABzMTfeDYoA).

Comment: Special thanks for the supplementary explanation of the code!

Comment: @JohnDizzle Glad that the explanation helped :)